# Rails RecordNotFound Page Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, categories, parameters

I am trying to show each page of a category through Index, but I am receiving the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController#index
Couldn't find Category with 'id'=
```

categories_controller.rb

```
def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <div class="page-row">
      <h4><%= category.id %></h4>
            <% for page in @category.pages do %>
      <p><%= page.title %></p>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

Please let me know if any additional info is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Look at `@category` instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you're doing with the @category = Category.find(params[:id]), that's unnecessary.  You're basically asking it to find a category with an ID, but since this is an index the id is usually not provided because you're view all the categories.  (You could have something more complex obviously)

If I wrote the index it would be like

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <div class="page-row">
  <h4><%= category.id %></h4>
        <% for page in category.pages do %>
  <p><%= page.title %></p>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

But I don't know what the pages in the category are.

Comment: This worked. I knew I was close, thanks for the help.